# Is there any way i can deploy an analysis database incrementally without dropping all the existing data?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, process, ssas

in our production environment, we got big analysis database running, and as time moves on, we want to add some new features,
like adding additional dimension or metrics, and every time i do deploying, all the data will be dropped. and i have to do 
a another process full again, which is time consuming.
i wonder is there any way i can do incrementally update my AS database just like sql server?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you add a dimension you need to do a full rebuild so that all the combinations can be recomputed for the different intersections.